# Problema em chamar construtor base em construtor herdado em C++

Tags: c++, herança, construtor

Estou pegando estruturas de dados na faculdade em C++ e essa linguagem é muito louca.

Estou tentando chamar o construtor da classe mãe no construtor das classes herdeiras, mas aparece o seguinte erro:

> error: no matching function for call to Veiculo::Veiculo(std::__cxx11::string&)’

Aí vai o código:

```
veiculo.h

    #ifndef VEICULO_H_
    #define VEICULO_H_
    #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    class Veiculo {

    protected:
        string nome;

    public:

        Veiculo(const char *nome) {
            this->nome = string(nome);
            cout << "Criação de Veículo" << nome << endl;
        }

        ~Veiculo(){
            cout << "Destruição de Veículo" << nome << endl;
        }

    };

    class Terrestre : public Veiculo {
    public:

        Terrestre() : Veiculo(nome){
            this->nome = Veiculo::nome;
            cout << "Criação de Terrestre" << nome << endl;
        };

        ~Terrestre() : Veiculo() {
            cout << "Destruição de Terrestre" << nome << endl;
        }
    };

    class Aquatico : public Veiculo {
    public:

        Aquatico() : Veiculo(nome) {
            this->nome = Veiculo::nome;
            cout << "Criação de Aquatico" << nome << endl;
        };

        ~Aquatico() {
            cout << "Destruição de Aquatico" << nome << endl;
        }

    };

    class Aereo : public Veiculo {
    public:

        Aereo() : Veiculo(nome) {
            this->nome = Veiculo::nome;
            cout << "Criação de Aereo" << nome << endl;

        };

        ~Aereo() {
            cout << "Destruição de Aereo" << nome << endl;
        }

    };


    #endif /* VEICULO_H_ */
    `

principal.cpp:

    `
    #include <iostream>
    #include "veiculo.h"

    using namespace std;

    int main() {
        cout << "Segunda pratica de AED em C++" << endl;

        Veiculo v1("v1");
        Terrestre t1("t1");
        Aquatico aq1("aq1");
        Aereo ar1("ar1");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você está a utilizar construtores a receberem uma string no `main`:

```
int main() {
    ...
    Terrestre t1("t1");
```

Mas no construtor da classe não está essa definição:

```
Terrestre() : Veiculo(nome)
```

Está `Terrestre()` que não tem parâmetros. Em vez disso você quer fazer como fez na classe `Veiculo` e adicionar o parâmetro que falta, assim:

```
Terrestre(const char *nome) : Veiculo(nome){
```

E tem o mesmo problema para a classe `Aquatico` e `Aereo`.

Tem ainda outro erro, que é no destrutor de Terrestre, aqui:

```
~Terrestre() : Veiculo() {
```

Que está a chamar o construtor da base. Na verdade o destrutor não pode ter inicializadores. Para alem disso o compilador já gera código para chamar os destrutores das classes por ordem, das derivadas para a base.

Altere-o para:

```
~Terrestre() {
```